# How do I stub a path generating method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, stubbing

I'm writing a view spec, and it renders a view that contains the line (in haml):

```
=link_to new_post_path
```

but the spec fails with:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"post"}
```

I'm trying to stub the `new_post_path` method, as it's not actually important to the view spec, but haven't had any luck.

I've tried, within my spec, the following two variations without any luck:

```
           stub!(:new_post_path).and_return("this path isn't important")
controller.stub!(:new_post_path).and_return("this path isn't important")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `new_post_path` comes from the `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` module. You need to stub the method on that module

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.stub(:new_post_path).and_return("this path isn't important")
```

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that my error was actually elsewhere, but you did help me to find out how to stub it.

Comment: this only works for me if I use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.new_host_path` in my view as opposed to the normal `new_host_path` p.s. I'm using rspec 3.2 syntax `allow(Rails.application.routes.url_helpers).to receive(:new_host_path).and_return("/")`

Comment: @ryan2johnson9 If you figured it out, would you mind posting your solution? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

If you're *not* in a view spec, but find yourself needing to stub a path helpers, the following syntax works as of Rails 4.2.5; you'll need to `receive_message_chain` instead as described here:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/1038

To wit:

`allow(Rails.application).to receive_message_chain(:routes, :url_helpers, :new_post_path).and_return("this path isn't important")`

Comment: or you could just stub the view as in my answer above rather than stubbing Rails.application

Comment: That works if you are in a view spec (and admittedly that was the original question), but that wasn't the case I was grappling with. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

```
allow(view).to receive(:new_post_path).and_return("this path isn't important")
```

that is rspec 3.2 syntax

I guess the old syntax would be

```
view.stub(:new_post_path).and_return("this path isn't important")
```

Comment: I found this to work with RSpec 3.5. `view.stubs(:new_post_path).returns("this path isn't important")`